# Compare two objects in jQuery and get the difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Using jQuery I would like to compare 2 objects:

sourceArray:

```
var origArray = [{
    "Name": "Single",
    "URL": "xxx",
    "ID": 123
},
{
    "Name": "Double",
    "URL": "yyy",
    "ID":  345
},
{
    "Name": "Family",
    "URL": "zzz",
    "ID": 567
}];
```

destination array

```
var destArray = [{
    "Name": "Single",
    "URL": "xxx",
    "ID": 123
},
{
    "Name": "Double",
    "URL": "yyy",
    "ID":  888
},
{
    "Name": "Family",
    "URL": "zzz",
    "ID": 567
}];
```

What I would like to do, is compare the target object with the source object based on the `ID` and find the mis-matched entries with a description on the resultant object. So the result will look like this:

```
var resultArray = [{
    "Name": "Double",
    "URL": "yyy",
    "ID":  888,
    "desc": "missing in source" 
},
{
    "Name": "Double",
    "URL": "yyy",
    "ID": 345,
    "desc": "missing in destination"
}];
```

Any quick help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why would you limit your toolset to jQuery here? This is not what jQuery is designed for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a good use of jQuery, but here is some vanilla javascript that does what you want.

```
function objDiff(array1, array2) {
    var resultArray = []

    array2.forEach(function(destObj) {
        var check = array1.some(function(origObj) {
            if(origObj.ID == destObj.ID) return true
        })
        if(!check) {
            destObj.desc = 'missing in source'
            resultArray.push(destObj)
        }
    })

    array1.forEach(function(origObj) {
        var check = array2.some(function(destObj) {
            if(origObj.ID == destObj.ID) return true
        })
        if(!check) {
            origObj.desc = 'missing in destination'
            resultArray.push(origObj)
        }
    })

    return resultArray
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9gaxsLbz/1/

Comment: Pefect!!!. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to dedupe your array, this will work:

```
var merged = origArray.concat(destArray);
var unique = merged.filter(function(item) {
    return ~this.indexOf(item.ID) ? false : this.push(item.ID);
}, []);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljzor9c6/

If you are only wanting items that were duped, you can easily invert the condition:

```
var merged = origArray.concat(destArray);
var dupes  = merged.filter(function(item) {
    return ~this.indexOf(item.ID) ? true : !this.push(item.ID);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the items in the first array and put the ID's in a map, then loop through the items in the second array and remove the matching ID's and add the missing.

Then just loop through the map to create the objects in the resulting array:

```js
var origArray = [{
    "Name": "Single",
    "URL": "xxx",
    "ID": 123
},
{
    "Name": "Double",
    "URL": "yyy",
    "ID":  345
},
{
    "Name": "Family",
    "URL": "zzz",
    "ID": 567
}];

var destArray = [{
    "Name": "Single",
    "URL": "xxx",
    "ID": 123
},
{
    "Name": "Double",
    "URL": "yyy",
    "ID":  888
},
{
    "Name": "Family",
    "URL": "zzz",
    "ID": 567
}];

var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < origArray.length; i++) {
    map[origArray[i].ID] = 'source';
}
for (var i = 0; i < destArray.length; i++) {
    var id = destArray[i].ID;
    if (id in map) {
        delete map[id];
    } else {
        map[id] = 'destination';
    }
}
var resultArray = [];
for (key in map) {
    var arr = map[key] == 'source' ? origArray : destArray;
    for (var i = 0; arr[i].ID != key; i++) ;
    resultArray.push({
        Name: arr[i].Name,
        URL: arr[i].URL,
        ID: arr[i].ID,
        desc: 'missing in ' + map[key]
    });
}

// show result in StackOverflow snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(resultArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < oa.length; i++) {
    var idx = mIndexOf(oa[i].ID);
    if(idx > -1) {
        oa.splice(i, 1);
        da.splice(idx, 1);
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < oa.length; i++) {
    var ln = result.length;
    result[ln] = oa[i];
    result[ln].desc = "missing in destination";
}
for(var i = 0; i < da.length; i++) {
    var ln = result.length;
    result[ln] = da[i];
    result[ln].desc = "missing in origin";
}

function mIndexOf(id) {
    for(var i = 0; i < oa.length; i++)
        if(oa[i].ID == id)
            return i;
    return -1;
}

console.log(result);
```

> 0: Object
>   ID: 345
>   Name: "Double"
>   URL: "yyy"
>   desc: "missing in destination"
>
> 1: Object
>   ID: 888
>   Name: "Double"
>   URL: "yyy"
>   desc: "missing in origin"

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/6crbcke5/1/)

Answer (score -1):

For things like this, you should use [lodash](https://lodash.com/). With lodash you can just do this:

```
var resultArray = _.defaults(destArray, origArray);
```

Comment: `_.defaults` merges two objects without overwriting keys in `destArray`. It does not solve the asker's problem, in which he wants to compare two objects and find their disjoint set.